# How to exit a macro where the current sheet grand total = 0 (no values picked up in the pivot table)

Tags: excel, vba

I've recorder a VBA Macro which works well and does what I want, however the issue is when there isn't any values the Macro Breaks and doesn't work, is there anyway to check the current sheet's pivot table for when it = 0 e.g. Count of Number field, the Macro ends the sub?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `Exit Sub` to exit any sub at any time based on any condition.

Comment: Hi @braX , thanks for the reply! Do you know any way to put this in an IF statement condition where the if Pivot Table = 0, the Exit Sub applies?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you have tried.